# How can I control the number of digits to right of the decimal point?

Tags: numerics, output-formatting

I have a problem concerning the number of decimal places in numerical output.

Given the output

```
0.00578493736389
```

I want the output to 10 decimal places only; that is

```
0.0057849374
```

I used

```
N[exp,n]
```

but I didn't get the answer I wanted.

Please help me.

Comment: See: [Change the format of numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ChangeTheFormatOfNumbers.html).

Comment: If you read the documentation for `N`, it states that "With machine-precision input, the results are always machine precision".  You probably want to use `NumberForm` to change the way the number is displayed rather than `N` to change the precision.

Comment: thank you very much. I do it. But what actually meaning "With machine-precision input," it is from computer?

Comment: Basically unless you specify more than about 16 significant digits in a number containing a decimal point _Mathematica_ will assume you want a machine precision number (effectively an IEEE double) and calculations involving that number will be done with machine precision.  _Mathematica_ can also use exact numbers (e.g. rationals) and arbitrary precision numbers, e.g. ``1.2345`30`` where the precision is tracked during calculations.  Perhaps a good place to start is [Exact and Approximate Results](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html)

Comment: thank you @MikeLimaOscar for good ecplaination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html).

```
x = 0.00578493736389;
```

> `0.00578494`

```
x // FullForm
```

> `` 0.00578493736389` ``

```
Precision @ x
```

> `MachinePrecision`

The evaluations given above are have been done to show you some tools for seeing what you are dealing with. Now let's apply `NumberForm`.

```
NumberForm[x, {∞, 10}]
```

> `0.0057849374`

`NumberForm` can be tricky to use. Read the documentation article on it fully and carefully. In particular, keep in mind that it only affects the the way a number is displayed. It does not affect the internal representation of the number.

Comment: thanks a lot for very useful comment